# Starting problems with OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, glfw

Everytime I am running this code it will give me a white window with the loading cursor of death. After some seconds the window is marked as non responding.

This is my code that I have written:

```
GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();
    
    if (!GLFW.glfwInit())
        throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't initialize GLFW");
    
    long window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(1200, 750, "WorldCraft", MemoryUtil.NULL, MemoryUtil.NULL);
    //GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Enable v-sync
    
    Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (GLFW.glfwGetCurrentContext() == MemoryUtil.NULL) {
                GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
                GLFW.glfwSwapInterval(1);
                GLFW.glfwShowWindow(window);
                GL.createCapabilities();
            }
            System.out.println("Begin Render");
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            GLFW.glfwPollEvents();
            GL11.glPushMatrix();
            
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            
            GL11.glColor3f(0.65F, 0.34F, 0.15F);
            GL11.glVertex3d(8, 0, 8);
            GL11.glVertex3d(-8, 0, 8);
            GL11.glVertex3d(8, 0, -8);
            GL11.glVertex3d(-8, 0, -8);
            
            GL11.glEnd();
            
            GL11.glPopMatrix();
            GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            System.out.println("End Render");
        }
        
    });
    timer.start();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The quad is perpendicular the viewport. You have to draw the geometry in the xy plane rather than the xz plane.

Comment: I have tried it, but I don't know whether it is rendering or not, because the OpenGL window is everytime not responding...

Comment: It happens when Windows detect that the event queue is unchanged for some time. Your timer is set to 100ms which is long but should be enough. Did you try to print something in your actionPerformed ? Just to see if the code is well executed every 100ms

Comment: I have added a System.out.println() at the begin and at the end of my actionPerformed, but it seems to be never called. Normally the timer should call the actionPerformed, shouldn't it?

Comment: Now I put a System.out.println() before and behind every line of code and I have detected that actionPerformed() is called but it seems glfwShowWindow() is causing the problem.

Comment: Okay, it explain why windows detect the window as inactive. You say that calling "GLFW.glfwShowWindow(window)" is causing the problem, why ? Is there an exception ? 
You can go with the debugger, it will be easier

Comment: I looked into the javadoc and it seems only to work in the main thread, so I moved it out of the actionPerformed() into my main method and now it is rendering, but I the window is still marked as not responding. And my Quad only seems to be rendered if its location is near 0 0 0, but I don't know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Does your program poll for events?

Comment: GLFW.glwfPollEvents() is present in my code and I never removed it. I don't know why I can't interact with the OpenGL window and why it is marked as not responding...

Comment: I didn't ask if it was present in your code - does it *happen*?

Comment: I don't know it seems to be called but I don't know if it is doing anything...

Comment: My previous problem with the not responding window is still present, but now I am trying to render multiple quads but it seems that they will only be rendered if they near the point at 0, 0, 0. I already searched for a way to move the camera view but somehow it doesn't work...